# images not defined, foreach img in directory, run js function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying to make a website, that will get each image in a directory (server side) from a folder, and then call a function to display the current image in a card, and keep doing that until it has been done for every image.

I have this, probably very innefficient code:

```html
<script> 
function addRow(imgURL) {


  const carddiv = document.createElement('carddiv');

  carddiv.className = 'card';
  carddiv.style = "width: 18rem;"

  carddiv.innerHTML = `
  <img src="`+ imgURL +`" class="card-img-top home-card-image-restrict" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 style="text-align: center;" class="card-title">Marli</h5>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">See Gallery</button>
</div>
</div>
  `;

  document.getElementById('displayCards').appendChild(carddiv);

}


 </script> 

<?php
$files = scandir('images/Marli');
foreach($files as $file) {



echo $file, "<br>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">addRow(', $file, ');</script>'; 

}
?>
```

When I run it, I just get an error in the console for each image, saying " is not defined"

I have been trying to get this to work for several hours, so I could really do with some help
Note, this is my first time using php code.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're passing in the full path to each image, which includes the directory

```
<?php
        $directoryName = 'images/Marli';
        $files = scandir($directoryName);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">addRow("/', $directoryName, '/', $file, '");</script>';
        }
    ?>
```